# How to copy bone animations, non-mirrored

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a rig that is not a typical L/R biped. It has N/S/E/W limbs. The limbs have fairly complex rigging that I'd like to avoid having to individually animate. Without the mirror functionality, is there a way to copy action keyframes from "east bone X" to the corresponding north, south and west bones?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change your Timeline at the bottom of your screen to Dope Sheet. Next, select the keyframes from your east bone X and duplicate them to your other limbs. You should see under the Dope Sheet Summary each of your limbs. This has worked for me when I need to copy my animations to other limbs. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have the selection of the _east_ bones in Dope Sheet done. I have the _north_ bones selected, but do not see the keyframes pasting to them, when executing Paste Keyframes (Ctrl V.) How do **you** paste keyframes?

Comment: If your rig is one object, you should be able to duplicate (Shift D) the bones to the other limbs in the Dope Sheet. If the limbs are separate objects, try joining them as one (Ctrl J) and then duplicate the bones.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste keyframes directly, at least in the graph editor, which is where I do it.  The bones do not have to have the same name.  The unintuitive thing that throws people is that for the paste to work, the destination bone must have keyframes in the appropriate channels.

Select all four bones and keyframe loc/rot/scale.  Animate and keyframe one bone however you'd like.  Go to frame 1.  Open a graph editor, select all keyframes for the animated bone, and ctrl c copy.  Select the other three bones and ctrl v paste.  Your keyframes will be duplicated to all three of those bones.

This might work in other views than a graph editor, I'm not sure; I'm only familiar with its use in the graph editor viewport.  If you are not at frame 1, the keyframes will be copied with an offset.

Comment: "The unintuitive thing that throws people is that for the paste to work, the destination bone must have keyframes in the appropriate channels." Exactly right. An F-curve must already exist for the channel, or the paste won't work. Which is indeed counter-intuitive. Any idea why it works this way?

Comment: @R-800 No idea :)